# Why is there unused, empty space between ELF sections?

Tags: linux, gcc, elf, binutils

It seems that binaries created with gcc 4.9.2 on Linux (Ubuntu 15.04, 32-bit) have a couple of thousand unused bytes between sections `.eh_frame` and `.init_array`. Example output from `objdump -h` for a simple executable:

```
Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
[...]
 16 .eh_frame     000000c0  080484ac  080484ac  000004ac  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 17 .init_array   00000004  08049f08  08049f08  00000f08  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
[...]
```

`.eh_frame` ends at file offset 0x56c but `.init_array` starts at 0xf08 leaving a hole of 0x99c = 2460 bytes. All other sections start immediately after the end of the previous section.

The size of the unused space varies, making it hard to observe how certain changes affect code size.

Where does this hole come from? Is there a way to avoid it?

**Update:** Output of `ld --verbose`:

```
$ cat so.c

int main() {
    return 0;
}

$ gcc so.c -Wl,--verbose -o so
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.25
  Supported emulations:
   elf_i386
   i386linux
   elf32_x86_64
   elf_x86_64
   elf_l1om
   elf_k1om
   i386pep
   i386pe
using internal linker script:
==================================================
/* Script for -z combreloc: combine and sort reloc sections */
/* Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   Copying and distribution of this script, with or without modification,
   are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
   notice and this notice are preserved.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386", "elf32-i386",
              "elf32-i386")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386)
ENTRY(_start)
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/i686-linux-gnu/lib32"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib32"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib32"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib32"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/i686-linux-gnu/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib/i386-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib");
SECTIONS
{
  /* Read-only sections, merged into text segment: */
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x08048000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x08048000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  .interp         : { *(.interp) }
  .note.gnu.build-id : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
  .hash           : { *(.hash) }
  .gnu.hash       : { *(.gnu.hash) }
  .dynsym         : { *(.dynsym) }
  .dynstr         : { *(.dynstr) }
  .gnu.version    : { *(.gnu.version) }
  .gnu.version_d  : { *(.gnu.version_d) }
  .gnu.version_r  : { *(.gnu.version_r) }
  .rel.dyn        :
    {
      *(.rel.init)
      *(.rel.text .rel.text.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
      *(.rel.fini)
      *(.rel.rodata .rel.rodata.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.r.*)
      *(.rel.data.rel.ro .rel.data.rel.ro.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.*)
      *(.rel.data .rel.data.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.d.*)
      *(.rel.tdata .rel.tdata.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.td.*)
      *(.rel.tbss .rel.tbss.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.tb.*)
      *(.rel.ctors)
      *(.rel.dtors)
      *(.rel.got)
      *(.rel.bss .rel.bss.* .rel.gnu.linkonce.b.*)
      *(.rel.ifunc)
    }
  .rel.plt        :
    {
      *(.rel.plt)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rel_iplt_start = .);
      *(.rel.iplt)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rel_iplt_end = .);
    }
  .init           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.init)))
  }
  .plt            : { *(.plt) *(.iplt) }
  .text           :
  {
    *(.text.unlikely .text.*_unlikely .text.unlikely.*)
    *(.text.exit .text.exit.*)
    *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
    *(.text.hot .text.hot.*)
    *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf32.em.  */
    *(.gnu.warning)
  }
  .fini           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.fini)))
  }
  PROVIDE (__etext = .);
  PROVIDE (_etext = .);
  PROVIDE (etext = .);
  .rodata         : { *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*) }
  .rodata1        : { *(.rodata1) }
  .eh_frame_hdr : { *(.eh_frame_hdr) }
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RO { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gcc_except_table
  .gcc_except_table.*) }
  /* These sections are generated by the Sun/Oracle C++ compiler.  */
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.exception_ranges
  .exception_ranges*) }
  /* Adjust the address for the data segment.  We want to adjust up to
     the same address within the page on the next page up.  */
  . = ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) - ((CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - .) & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)); . = DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE), CONSTANT (COMMONPAGESIZE));
  /* Exception handling  */
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RW { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.exception_ranges .exception_ranges*) }
  /* Thread Local Storage sections  */
  .tdata          : { *(.tdata .tdata.* .gnu.linkonce.td.*) }
  .tbss           : { *(.tbss .tbss.* .gnu.linkonce.tb.*) *(.tcommon) }
  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  }
  .init_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.init_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  }
  .fini_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.fini_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  }
  .ctors          :
  {
    /* gcc uses crtbegin.o to find the start of
       the constructors, so we make sure it is
       first.  Because this is a wildcard, it
       doesn't matter if the user does not
       actually link against crtbegin.o; the
       linker won't look for a file to match a
       wildcard.  The wildcard also means that it
       doesn't matter which directory crtbegin.o
       is in.  */
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.ctors))
    /* We don't want to include the .ctor section from
       the crtend.o file until after the sorted ctors.
       The .ctor section from the crtend file contains the
       end of ctors marker and it must be last */
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.ctors))
  }
  .dtors          :
  {
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.dtors))
  }
  .jcr            : { KEEP (*(.jcr)) }
  .data.rel.ro : { *(.data.rel.ro.local* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.local.*) *(.data.rel.ro .data.rel.ro.* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.*) }
  .dynamic        : { *(.dynamic) }
  .got            : { *(.got) *(.igot) }
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_RELRO_END (SIZEOF (.got.plt) >= 12 ? 12 : 0, .);
  .got.plt        : { *(.got.plt)  *(.igot.plt) }
  .data           :
  {
    *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
    SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
  }
  .data1          : { *(.data1) }
  _edata = .; PROVIDE (edata = .);
  . = .;
  __bss_start = .;
  .bss            :
  {
   *(.dynbss)
   *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
   *(COMMON)
   /* Align here to ensure that the .bss section occupies space up to
      _end.  Align after .bss to ensure correct alignment even if the
      .bss section disappears because there are no input sections.
      FIXME: Why do we need it? When there is no .bss section, we don't
      pad the .data section.  */
   . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 32 / 8 : 1);
  }
  . = ALIGN(32 / 8);
  . = SEGMENT_START("ldata-segment", .);
  . = ALIGN(32 / 8);
  _end = .; PROVIDE (end = .);
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_END (.);
  /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
  .stab          0 : { *(.stab) }
  .stabstr       0 : { *(.stabstr) }
  .stab.excl     0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
  .stab.exclstr  0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
  .stab.index    0 : { *(.stab.index) }
  .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
  .comment       0 : { *(.comment) }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
  /* DWARF 1 */
  .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
  .line           0 : { *(.line) }
  /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
  .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
  .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
  .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
  /* DWARF 2 */
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line .debug_line.* .debug_line_end ) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
  .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
  .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
  .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
  .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
  /* DWARF 3 */
  .debug_pubtypes 0 : { *(.debug_pubtypes) }
  .debug_ranges   0 : { *(.debug_ranges) }
  /* DWARF Extension.  */
  .debug_macro    0 : { *(.debug_macro) }
  .gnu.attributes 0 : { KEEP (*(.gnu.attributes)) }
  /DISCARD/ : { *(.note.GNU-stack) *(.gnu_debuglink) *(.gnu.lto_*) }
}


==================================================
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crti.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crti.o
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/crtbegin.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/crtbegin.o
attempt to open /tmp/ccQ0fTTK.o succeeded
/tmp/ccQ0fTTK.o
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc.a succeeded
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc_s.so succeeded
-lgcc_s (/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc_s.so)
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/libc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/libc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libc.so succeeded
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libc.so
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libc.so
attempt to open /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 succeeded
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
attempt to open /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a succeeded
(/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
attempt to open /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2 succeeded
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc.a succeeded
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc_s.so succeeded
-lgcc_s (/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc_s.so)
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/crtend.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/crtend.o
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crtn.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crtn.o
ld-linux.so.2 needed by /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
found ld-linux.so.2 at /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2
```

Comment: Output of `ld --verbose`? Note that `.eh_frame` is `READONLY`, while `.init_array` isn't. `.init_array` is probably positioned so relocations that can be fixed up at load-time can later be marked read-only, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8062/dtors-looks-writable-but-attempts-to-write-segfault

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three regions of memory to consider there:

- Read-only data.
- Non-lazy relocations that can be fixed up at load time.
- Data.

Now, the `.eh_frame` section is marked `READONLY`, so it goes into the first section.

`.init_array` is an array of function pointers to initialization functions, which can be resolved to their absolute addresses when loading the program/library, and then marked read-only (writing to function pointers is a common way to exploit vulnerabilities), so it goes into the second region.

The relevant parts of the linker script are:

```
[...]
.eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RO { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) }
[...]
/* Adjust the address for the data segment.  We want to adjust up to
   the same address within the page on the next page up.  */
. = ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) - ((CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - .) & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1));
. = DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE), CONSTANT (COMMONPAGESIZE));
[...]
.init_array     :
[...]
.got            : { *(.got) *(.igot) }
. = DATA_SEGMENT_RELRO_END (SIZEOF (.got.plt) >= 12 ? 12 : 0, .);
.got.plt        : { *(.got.plt)  *(.igot.plt) }
.data           :
[...]
. = DATA_SEGMENT_END (.);
```

You can consult the documentation for builtin functions for GNU ld linker scripts at https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Builtin-Functions.html. But beware that `DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN` documentation is incorrect, as reported by Stephen Kell at [binutils bug #19203: "DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN documentation is not consistent with behaviour"](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19203), apparently since Jakub Jelinek's [[PATCH] Fix DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2002-03/msg00198.html). `DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN` itself was introduced at a binutils' mailing list thread called [[RFC PATCH] Smarter aligning of data segment](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2002-02/msg00265.html).

Somehow, the following:

```
. = ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) - ((CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - .) & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1));
. = DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE), CONSTANT (COMMONPAGESIZE));
```

causes a 1-page jump, which in your example would move you from 0x0804856c to 0x0804956c.

When the linker option `-z relro` is used, requesting relocations fixed up at load time to be marked read-only, `DATA_SEGMENT_RELRO_END` causes the previous `DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN` to add enough padding to cause the sum of the two arguments of `DATA_SEGMENT_RELRO_END` to be aligned to a new page.

So, assuming `.got.plt` has at least three pointers, those first three pointers (which are used right away by the loader) will be in the second region, and the rest of `.got.plt` on the third.

The padding added by `DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN` moves you from 0x0804956c to 0x08049f08. When everything that can be mprotected read-only after fix-ups is emitted, you'll be at 0x0804a000, in a new page, which will be kept read-write.

Comment: Do you now why they align to "the same address within the page on the next page up", rather than just starting on the next page at 0x08049000? Is that so there's less changes in addresses?

Comment: @viraptor: only guessing, but I think it's done that way to avoid having to move to the next "page" on the file image, while having the "offsets" still matching on file and memory.

Comment: The "Smarter aligning of data segment" thread you linked contains the answer to my question. The whole mechanism trades some additional on-disk file size for reduced runtime memory consumption.